# Is there any way to put a variable inside telnet command in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet, telnetlib

is there any way to put the variable **posorprom** inside the telnet command in python?
Here is a peace of my code:

```
posorprom = prom

tn.write(b"ls /mnt/flash/prom | wc -l\n")
```

i want to put the variable posorprom inside the command, so i already tried this:

```
tn.write(b"ls /mnt/flash/" + posorprom + " | wc -l\n")
```

but it doesnt work.
please help me.

Comment: For future questions please include the actual errors you get, copy-pasted (as text) in full and complete. "It doesn't work" is just not good enough. And please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Mario Aren't you interested in an answer anymore?

Comment: hello again, i used both answers but i stll have the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well you seem to concatenate different kinds of strings, since you use raw byte strings for one string, then *all* the strings must be that:

```
posorprom = b"prom"
tn.write(b"ls /mnt/flash/" + posorprom + b" | wc -l\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

`posorprom = prom`
does not set the variable posoprom to "prom", but to the value of the variable prom.

Try `posorprom = "prom"` instead.

`posorprom = "prom"
tn.write("ls /mnt/flash/" + posorprom + " | wc -l\n")`